# Understanding the complex circuitry in supplying voltage to an IC chip

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, integrated-circuit

I'm very new to microcontrollers and I'm trying to understand the purpose of the [pinouts of an IC](http://www.ti.com/product/TRF7970A/datasheet/terminal_configuration_and_functions#SLOS743156) so that I can interface it to a microcontroller. Most of the pinout description from the datasheet are straight forward, but then I look at a [sample application schematic](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TRF7970A) and it's gotten really complex and confusing. In particular, the part circled in red that deals with supplying the necessary voltages.

[image]

Most of the microcontroller projects I've worked with simply required a supply of Vcc and ground, so I'm having a really hard time in why all those circuitry is necessary. Are there any resources I can look into to understand where that circuitry design came from? A simple explanation on their purposes would be most appreciated.

Comment: Dave Jones has a great video on the use of bypass capacitors and why they need to be placed near the power pins... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcJ6UdDx1vg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bit of a special case that you probably don't have to worry about if new to microcontrollers. This microcontroller is interacting with a radio so has to deal with radio frequency signals.  There is an antenna connection there which has components not related to voltage supply in the most lower left.  And this microcontroller has many different supply voltages that must be supplied - most microcontrollers will just have one supply voltage!

Usually just put a 0.1uF capacitor at the input voltage pin near the microcontroller and a larger 10uF or bigger anywhere on the circuitboard and you should be fine.

If you want to get into microcontrollers, this probably isn't the one to start with. But don't let that stop you from playing with NFC or RFID communications with a microcontroller - you can get more easy to use NFC or RFID kits to hook up to with a more basic microcontroller that won't need radio frequency expertise to use.

Comment: I've done some NFC communication on the software side (Android), so I wanted to play around with the hardware side. I don't intend to interface with a radio, so am I correct to understand that I can just put a capacitor on wherever I'm supplying the voltage, and I should be fine?

Comment: Yep, 0.1uF, usually a ceramic capacitor, to be placed near the microcontroller but other values should be fine if in that sort of range.